# Spring, JPA, Hibernate, Jetty 7 Integration

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jetty

Have anyone successfully run any spring and JPA application in jetty 7? I am getting following exception. This application throws no error in jetty 6.

```
INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter(org.eclipse.jetty.util.log) via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - jetty-7.1.2.v20100523
INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Deployment monitor G:\_Java\_Jetty\jetty-distribution-7.1.2.v20100523\contexts at interval 5
INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Deployment monitor G:\_Java\_Jetty\jetty-distribution-7.1.2.v20100523\webapps at interval 5
INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Deployable added: G:\_Java\_Jetty\jetty-distribution-7.1.2.v20100523\webapps\gwtrpc-spring.war
INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Copying WEB-INF/lib jar:file:/G:/_Java/_Jetty/jetty-distribution-7.1.2.v20100523/webapps/gwtrpc-spring.war!/WEB-INF/lib/ to C:\Documents and Settings\Jewel2\Local Settings\Temp\Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_gwtrpc.spring.war__gwtrpc.spring__az1wdj\webinf\WEB-INF\lib
INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Copying WEB-INF/classes from jar:file:/G:/_Java/_Jetty/jetty-distribution-7.1.2.v20100523/webapps/gwtrpc-spring.war!/WEB-INF/classes/ to C:\Documents and Settings\Jewel2\Local Settings\Temp\Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_gwtrpc.spring.war__gwtrpc.spring__az1wdj\webinf\WEB-INF\classes
INFO [main] /gwtrpc-spring - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO [main] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO [main] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jun 10 00:13:32 GMT+06:00 2010]; root of context hierarchy
INFO [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
INFO [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@467991: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,greetingServiceImpl,testService,testService2,taskExecutor,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO [main] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService  'taskExecutor'
INFO [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
INFO [main] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'gwtrpc-spring-data-source'
INFO [main] org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.4.0.GA
INFO [main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
INFO [main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
INFO [main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO [main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
INFO [main] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.1.0.GA
INFO [main] org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.4.0.GA
INFO [main] org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration - Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
 name: gwtrpc-spring-data-source
 ...]
INFO [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@467991: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,greetingServiceImpl,testService,testService2,taskExecutor,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager,org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO [main] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskExecutor'
ERROR [main] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: gwtrpc-spring-data-source] class or package not found
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1403)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:636)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:995)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:579)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:381)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:182)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:497)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:436)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:349)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:306)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.start(Scanner.java:242)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:136)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:562)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:212)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:209)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1018)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:983)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:447)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:605)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:238)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: gwtrpc-spring-data-source] class or package not found
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1093)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:871)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:758)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:425)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:131)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
 ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WEB-INF.classes.org.gwtrpcspring.example.server.Person
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:135)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1009)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1081)
 ... 53 more
WARN [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Failed startup of context WebAppContext@149f041@149f041/gwtrpc-spring,file:/C:/Documents and Settings/Jewel2/Local Settings/Temp/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_gwtrpc.spring.war__gwtrpc.spring__az1wdj/webinf/;jar:file:/G:/_Java/_Jetty/jetty-distribution-7.1.2.v20100523/webapps/gwtrpc-spring.war!/;,G:\_Java\_Jetty\jetty-distribution-7.1.2.v20100523\webapps\gwtrpc-spring.war
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: gwtrpc-spring-data-source] class or package not found
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1403)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:545)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
 at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:636)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:995)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:579)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:381)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:182)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:497)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:61)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:436)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:349)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:306)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.start(Scanner.java:242)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:136)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:562)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:212)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:209)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1018)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:983)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:447)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:605)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.parseCommandLine(Main.java:238)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: gwtrpc-spring-data-source] class or package not found
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1093)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addClassesToSessionFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:871)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:758)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:425)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:131)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
 ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WEB-INF.classes.org.gwtrpcspring.example.server.Person
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:135)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.classForName(Ejb3Configuration.java:1009)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addNamedAnnotatedClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:1081)
 ... 53 more
INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

And this is my applicationContext.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>

 <context:annotation-config />

 <context:component-scan base-package="org.gwtrpcspring.example.server" />

 <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
  <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
  <property name="username" value="jewel" />
  <property name="password" value="jewel" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    <!-- 
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
     -->

    <property name="showSql" value="false" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
   </bean>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <tx:annotation-driven />

 <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


</beans>
```

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but... what are you using from Jetty 7 that you don't get in Jetty 6? If the answer is nothing, just stick with Jetty 6 and give some time to Jetty 7 to become more stable.

Comment: Hi Pascal, thanks for your response. Yes, I also think so but unfortunately I am using Cometd in my project and they seems to solve some critical bug in jetty7 code. For example see this: http://groups.google.com/group/cometd-users/browse_thread/thread/fde24f3cbdaaadee/472103e24a3813f8?lnk=gst&q=Unknown+client+jetty7#472103e24a3813f8

Comment: Ah, I see. I suggest creating a new bug in [Jetty's bug tracker](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Contributor/Bug_Tracking), maybe you'll get more feedback there.

Answer (score 2):

I got some time to fight with this issue again. It seems the class loading is the main problem. Hibernate wrongly interpreted the package as:

`WEB-INF.classes.org.gwtrpcspring.example.server.Person`

I just zipped all the stuff of `WEB-INF/classes` to `WEB-INF/lib` and everything is working fine.